# can I prefetchnta stack pointer?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

My program, written completely in x64 AVX2 assembly, has a subroutine that's called extremely large number of times. The subroutine starts with

```
push rax
push rbx
push rcx,
... and ends with ...
pop rcx
pop rbx
pop rax
ret
```

Now I obviously want to speed up this push-pop process, so am wondering, if I can give a command like this before :

```
prefetchnta byte ptr [rsp]
prefetch0 [rsp]
push rax
prefetch0 [rsp]
push rbx
... and similarly, at exit
prefetchnta byte ptr rsp
prefetch0 [rsp]
pop rbx
prefetch0 [rsp]
pop rax
ret
```

Would like to know if this has any benefit in accelerating the push pop process?

While at it, can I verify that in one call, prefetchnta loads 64 bytes in Haswell Core i7 4770K processor?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Sounds like it should work, but why 2 prefetches to the same address? As for the sizes - any prefetch would bring a full cacheline

Comment: Makes no sense whatsoever, your code doesn't read from the stack, it writes.  The stack is always hot anyway.

Comment: @Leor, its not two prefetches to same address, the prefetches bring it up the cache levels

Comment: @ Hans Passant - it writes to stack at push, and reads off the stack at Pop, and I am not sure what you meant by stack is hot anyway - could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @user1104214: the processor organizes cache contents based on some sort of least-recently-used / most-frequently-used metrics. Since the stack is essentially used all the time when calling functions (`call`/`ret` write to / read from the stack), and when saving/restoring nonvolatile registers, one can reasonably assume the memory around the top of the stack is always cached (it must've been fetched _before_ the code using it executed).